# Optimzed Journey plan planning

Tags: algorithm

I have a problem to solve.

**Problem Statement**:

I have set of around 5000 stores with there geo-coordinates.Every store has to be visited once in order collect order recipt from the stores.

This will be done by salesman.

I want to generate N optimized journey plans, such that every salesman is able to cover maximum no. of stores within **8 hours**.

i.e in a Journey plan the time taken to visit all the stores should not be more than 8 hours.

and no two salesman should visit same store.

i.e once a store is visited should not be visited again in another Journey plan.

In this case No. of journey plans generated is indirectly equal to no. of salesmen required.

**Final Result required**:

Minimize the no. of journey plan to cover all the stores

**What I Have:**

Store-to-store distance Matrix. which has distance coverd and time taken, between each and every store

**Challange**:
I do not have any information on salesman(i'e i don't have their geo locations) which makes it tough to choose the start point for every Journey Plan.

**My Initial Thoughts:**

I'm thinking of dividing the stores into different regions through clustering. and then form Journey plan for each cluster(for optimized route).

I'll be developing this in python.

Any Ideas on what would be the best way to attempt and proceed in such type of problem.

Comment: When a salesman finishes a journey plan are there any  constraints where his next journey plan can start? Or can we put him anywhere on the map for his next journey? Also, should the time to visit a store also be considered?

Comment: @SaiBot I'm considering in here that one salesman will only visit one journey plan. i'e no of jouenyplans generated = no of salesman. therefore we can start the next journeyplan from anywhere

Comment: @SaiBot No particular time to visit a store

Comment: Ah sorry I didn't catch that its actually well explained in your question

Comment: Isn't this an instance of the multiple traveling salesman problem, mTSP?

Answer (score 0):

Here is an idea for an heuristic:

1. Start with one salesman per store. Each salesman stores the covered path (e.g. list of store ids), which starts with their initial store only, and they start with 0 time spent.
2. Pick the shortest uncovered link between two stores, `s1` and `s2`, with a time cost of `t`.
3. Look for the pair of salesmen `a1` and `a2` such that their paths begin or end at `s1` and `s2`. If you cannot find such pair (because the stores are already in the middle of an existing path, or `s1` and `s2` are the beginning and end of the path of one salesman), discard the link and go back to 2.
4. Let `t_sum` be the sum of the time spent by `a1`, the time spent by `a2` and `t`. If `t_sum` is less than the maximum time `T` that each salesman can spend (8 hours), discard the link and go back to 2.
5. Merge `a1` and `a2` into a single salesman. This procedure changes a bit depending on the exact situation, but it should be fairly trivial. For example, if `a1` ends at `s1` and `a2` begins at `s2` you can just concatenate their paths, but if `a1` begins at `s1` and `a2` begins at `s2` then you would have to (for example) reverse the path of `a1` and then concatenate them. The new salesman has a spent time of `t_sum`.
6. Go to 2. and repeat until no unexplored links remain.

That is the basic idea. There is some room to decide what data structures to use exactly, affecting how you look for the next shortest link, how you look for `a1` and `a2` and how you keep track of covered/discarded links. There is also a number of improvements or optimizations you may include:

- When you merge `a1` and `a2`, you can discard all the links to `s1` and `s2` unless they are the only elements in the path of `a1` or `a2`. For example, if I am looking at the link between stores `1` and `2` and I am merging the paths `[1, 3, 4]` and `[2]` (resulting in `[2, 1, 3, 4]` or `[4, 3, 1, 2]`), I can remove all the remaining links of store `1`, because now it is in the middle of a path, but not from `2`, because it still at one end of the merged path and therefore open to connection.
- When you merge `a1` and `a2`, if `T - t_sum < t` then this salesman will not possibly be merged any further (because the cost of every remaining link will be at least `t`), so you can "close" the path, meaning you can discard the links at each end and, if that may save you time (depends on the exact implementation), you can skip `a1` and `a2` when searching in the next executions of step 3.
- In fact, if the graph is very dense, you may save time checking, on each iteration or on every few ones, if the difference between `T` and the remaining time for any of the currently "active" agents is less than the last value `t`, and "close" it if that is the case.

*EDIT:*

Here is a Python proof of concept. I avoided using NumPy or any other external packages, although since the algorithm is mostly iterative I'm not sure you could make it much faster.

```python
def make_journeys(dists, max_dist):
    n = len(dists)
    ds = sorted((dists[i][j], i, j) for i in range(n) for j in range(i + 1, n))
    starts = list(range(n))
    ends = list(range(n))
    salesmen = [([i], 0) for i in range(n)]
    for d, i, j in ds:
        if starts[i] is not None and starts[j] is not None:
            si, sj = starts[i], starts[j]
            reverse_i, reverse_j = True, False
        elif starts[i] is not None and ends[j] is not None:
            si, sj = starts[i], ends[j]
            reverse_i, reverse_j = True, True
        elif ends[i] is not None and starts[j] is not None:
            si, sj = ends[i], starts[j]
            reverse_i, reverse_j = False, False
        elif ends[i] is not None and ends[j] is not None:
            si, sj = ends[i], ends[j]
            reverse_i, reverse_j = False, True
        else:
            continue
        if si == sj:
            continue
        (pi, di) = salesmen[si]
        (pj, dj) = salesmen[sj]
        dt = d + di + dj
        if dt > max_dist:
            continue
        starts[pi[0]] = None
        ends[pi[-1]] = None
        starts[pj[0]] = None
        ends[pj[-1]] = None
        if reverse_i:
            pi = list(reversed(pi))
        if reverse_j:
            pj = list(reversed(pj))
        pt = pi + pj
        starts[pt[0]] = si
        ends[pt[-1]] = si
        salesmen[si] = (pt, dt)
        salesmen[sj] = None
    return [s for s in salesmen if s]
```

The function returns a list of tuples with the path with the store ids and the total time of the journey. Here is a test:

```python
def random_symmetric(N, min, max):
    # Build a random symmetric matrix
    dists = [[random.randint(1, 9) if i != j else 0 for j in range(N)] for i in range(N)]
    return [[(dists[i][j] + dists[j][i]) // 2 for j in range(N)] for i in range(N)]

random.seed(100)

# This takes long!
distances = random_symmetric(5000, 1, 9)
max_distance = 100

journeys = make_journeys(distances, max_distance)
print('{} journeys computed.'.format(len(journeys)))
```

Output:

```
50 journeys computed.
```

In the above test, generating the random distances matrix takes quite a while (that would be much faster with NumPy). The call to `make_journeys` took ~16s in my computer. Obviously YMMV but it's not running for hours or minutes.